# About me page to reference package.json details

Tags: single-page-application, react-admin

This is my first app using react-admin and i would like to have a resource called "About" or "Information" which would show the details referencing my package.json like name, version, description and author.

{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is my application.",
  "author": "John Doe",
  "dependencies":{
  ...
  }
}

Not really sure how to go about this, and havent found anything similar on either stack overflow or online. Would think using "Show" is the way to go unless there is a better way.

Would appreciate some tips or even a link to documentation or to a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would think using "Show" is the way to go unless there is a better
>   way.

I realised afterwards that the above statement makes no sense.

So I created on the backend (which uses vertx3 and javax.ws.rs-api) to respond to the "GET" command with a JSON with all the details. This of course can only be shown by using a list.

At the moment I cannot make this prettier/better and have it look more like an "About" page.